# Constraint name for default value for sql server with alembic

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy, constraints, alembic

My alembic migration adds a column to a table like this:

`op.add_column("OrderTable", sa.Column("item_counter", sa.Integer(), nullable=False, server_default="0"))`

When I run the migration, SQL Server generates a `DF_Order_item_cou__39209daf` constraint because of the server_default which I must use to set the item_counter to 0 by default in a non-nullable column.

The problem is that running an alembic downgrade -1 fails because the constraint was generated by SQL Server and I don't seem to have control over constraint names that are created for default values.    I thought I could add to the naming_conventions dict that is in my MetaData in the Base model like so:

```
class Base(DeclarativeBase):
  metadata = MetaData(naming_convention: {
   "df": "df_%(table_name)s_%(column_0_name)s", ...
}
```

But these DF constraints seem particular to SQL Server and not sure how I can gain control over their names when using alembic and SQLAlchemy as described in [Alembic: The Importance of Naming Constraints](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/naming.html)

Comment: Isn't it `naming_convention` (singular)? If it isn't supporting default constraints then I'd suggest adding another issue to the [naming_convention issues on Alembic](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+naming_convention).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Alembic has a few special switches in the drop_column for dealing with SqlServer.   Read about them [here](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.drop_column)
What I needed was:

```
op.drop_column("OrderTable", "item_counter", mssql_drop_default=True)
```